# Getting error while uploading smarty files in online server

Tags: php, smarty

I am new in smarty, i have developed an application in smarty. It works fine in local server. I uploaded these files to the online server, it shows following errors.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'template property 'compiler_object' does not exist.' in D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php:953 Stack trace: #0 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(247): Smarty_Internal_Template->__get('compiler_object') #1 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(456): Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource() #2 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(567): Smarty_Internal_Template->renderTemplate() #3 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\Smarty.class.php(338): Smarty_Internal_Template->getRenderedTemplate() #4 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\Smarty.class.php(382): Smarty->fetch('index.tpl.html', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) #5 D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\index. in D:\inetpub\vhosts\mobmail.eu\httpdocs\libs\smarty-3.0.7\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php on line 953

I dont know why this error in my server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Gautam3164 this is the error while taking the home page "mobmail.eu"

Comment: @ Gautam3164 please go through [moblail](http://mobmail.eu)

Comment: i have just uploaded the files to the sever, then it got such an error

Comment: BUt without code we cont knw where the error located

Comment: what version of PHP running in online server?

Comment: Seems like you haven't created compile / cache directions to me. Or they weren't properly chmod'ded.

Comment: @ Muthu Kumaran, PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: @ fliespl, could you please tell the location of compile / cache

Comment: Smarty 3.0.7 is rather old. 3.1.12 is the most current version